# Convert complex mysql select into Rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've three table 'Hardware','Warehouse' and 'Brand' and tables are refernced together in this way: Hardware <-> Warehouse Hardware <-> Brand

Inside a warehouse view,I've a search dropdown menu that works in this way:you choose a 'Brand' from menu, and when you click on submit, application returns all warehouse objects associated to the and that you'v choosed.
Issue is that warehouse table is not related to brand as I shows before, so it'snt any foreign key that join warehouse and brand.
So I must try a way to convert this mysql query inside rails application:

SELECT w1.*  FROM warehouses w1, hardwares   h1 where w1.hardware_id = h1.id and h1.brand_id=3

This is my code:

```
class WarehousesController < ApplicationController
def search
        generate_selects true
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # search.html.erb
            format.js {render :partial => 'get_models'}
            format.xml  { render :xml => @warehouse }
        end
    end

    def search_result
        if request.post? && params[:from_form]
            session[:sa_query_flatten] = sa_query.flatten #Memorizzo sulla session per riutilizzarla in "aggregate_by_position" e will_paginate per page > 1
        end
        conditions  = session[:sa_query_flatten]
        logger.debug "QUERY: #{conditions} SESSION:#{session[:sa_query_flatten].inspect}"
        @products = Warehouse.find(:all,:conditions => conditions)
        @search_count = @products.count
        @products = @products.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
        @search_start = ((params[:page].to_i - 1)* 100) + 1
        @search_end = (params[:page].to_i * 100) - 1
        if @search_start < 0
        @search_start = @search_start + 100
        end
        if @search_end < 0
        @search_end = @search_end + 100
        end
        if @search_end > @search_count
        @search_end = @search_count
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end

def generate_selects(search)
        if !search
            @hardwares ||= Hardware.where({:brand_id => @warehouse.hardware.brand_id}).map{|hw| [hw.model,hw.id]}.sort
            if session[:user_role] != "administrator"
                @ingress_transport_documents = IngressTransportDocument.filtered_by_registry(session[:registry_id]).map{|itd| [itd.number,itd.id]}.sort
            else
                @ingress_transport_documents = IngressTransportDocument.all.map{|itd| [itd.number,itd.id]}.sort
            end
        end 
            @brands = Brand.all.map{|br| [br.name,br.id]}.sort
            @positions = Position.all.map{|pos| [pos.name,pos.id]}.sort
            @states = State.all.map{|st| [st.name,st.id]}.sort
            @logicalWH = Logicalwarehouse.all.map{|lw| [lw.name,lw.id]}.sort
            @extra = Extra.all.map{|ex| [ex.name,ex.id]}.sort
            @registries = Registry.all.map{|cs| [cs.name,cs.id]}.sort

    end


    def sa_query
        if params[:warehouse]
            session[:params_warehouse] = params[:warehouse]
        else
            params[:warehouse] = session[:params_warehouse]
        end
        query = String.new
        query_array = Array.new
        if params[:enable_asset] == "1"
            query << "asset LIKE ? AND "
            query_array.push(params[:asset] + "%")
        end
        if params[:enable_serial] == "1"
            query << "serial LIKE ? AND "
            query_array.push params[:serial] + "%"
        end
        if params[:enable_brand] == "1"
            query << "**brand** =>  = ? AND "
            query_array.push Brand.find(params[:brand]).name # Qui va messo brand, non brand_value
        end
        if params[:enable_model] == "1"
            query << "hardware_id.model = ? AND "
            query_array.push params[:model]
        end
        if params[:enable_position] == "1" 
            query << "position_id = ? AND "
            query_array.push params[:position]

        end
        if params[:enable_logicalwarehouse] == "1"
            query << "logicalwarehouse_id = ? AND "
            query_array.push params[:logicalwarehouse]
        end
        if query.index("AND ",-4) != nil
        query = query[0,query.length-5]
        end
        [query,query_array]
    end
```

Mysql wait **brand** as query input parameter, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My advice, if your using rails, is to step back and try to do more of the query in rails itself and to do so using the best model setup possible.

I would structure your 3 models as follows:

```
class Warehouse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many : brands
  has_many : hardwares, :through => brands
end


class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hardware
  belongs_to :warehouse
end

class Hardware < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands
  has_many :warehouses, :through => brands
end
```

This structure will then let you do the `Brand.hardwares` or `Brand.warehouses` queries that you want.  Just add in a `find` for the Brand you want.

Comment: ok and doing so should I add a foreign key in warehouse to link warehouse table with brand?